# How to use JavaScript to display id of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have html that contains many paragraph tags with an id such as the following:

```
<p id="123">some text</p>
```

What I want to do, is to display the id value within the `p` tag, preferably bolded.

So the above would create html of:

```
<p id="123"><b>123</b>: some text</p>
```

Any code samples that I have seen so far require that you already know the id or class value.

How do I do this with JavaScript?
Thank you.

Comment: “Insert Adjacent HTML” might help here.

Answer (score 4):

Select all the `p` elements using `querySelectorAll("p")` and then iterate over the returned collection and set the content of each `p` element using the `.innerHTML` property.

To set the content of each `p` element correctly, you need to concatenate the contents of each `p` element with its `id`. To make the `id` bold, you can wrap it in `strong` tag.

```js
const pTags = document.querySelectorAll('p');

pTags.forEach(p => {
    p.innerHTML = `<strong>${p.id}: </strong>${p.textContent}`
});
```

```html
<p id="123">Some Text</p>
<p id="456">Some Text</p>
<p id="789">Some Text</p>
```

Comment: Strangely, it's actually displaying the javascript itself as in:
     ${p.id}: ${p.textContent}

Comment: Did you use single or double quotes instead of backticks `\``?

Comment: I used single, like '

Comment: that won't work. You need to use template literal using backticks.